# Examples on translating raw data generated by YARD

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

On the [YARD readme](https://github.com/lsegal/yard), there is mention of `raw data` generated by YARD:

> YARD also outputs documented objects as raw data (the dumped
>   Namespace) which can be reloaded to do generation at a later date, or
>   even auditing on code. This means that any developer can use the raw
>   data to perform output generation for any custom format, such as YAML,
>   for instance.

What are examples/blogs/tutorials of using the `raw data` and translating it to other formats? For example, I am interested in transforming parts of the raw data into YAML.

Comment: It'd be be easier to answer this question if we had a example of the `raw data` you want transferred. But having said that have you tried to write the data to a `YAML`?

Comment: My experience with YARD is that the code and documentation are quite decent. I'd invest a couple of hours experimenting with it. I did not get much help from the community on detailed questions. Not because they don't want to I think, but everybody seems quite busy.